# I want to use gdb with my Qt project..But I received "Permission denied" message?

Tags: qt, memory-management, gdb, qt-creator, valgrind

I have a Qt Project on Ubuntu. I want to use valgrind analysis. 
And I wrote this command :  **gcc myApp.pro -o myApp -g**

But I received this error :  **File format not recognized**

OR I wrote this command : **valgrind ./myApp.pro**

I received this error : **./myApp.pro Permission denied**

What can I do for valgrind analysis (Using gdb)  ...

Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc` expects source files to be passed. `valgrind` expects executable file. Neither of them expects project file.

Firstly you need to compile your project as usual to produce an executable file. Then you should run valgrind like this:

```
valgrind -q --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=low \
   --suppressions=Qt47supp.txt ./[your-app-target-name]
```

Comment: I understand you. Thank you. But I received this error : --suppression=Qt47.supp.txt command not found .

Comment: Remove line break and `\\` in my command. Put all options on one line.

Comment: Still same error : **myApp.exe : Permission denied**  :(  I am using ubuntu so can be .exe ?

Comment: In Ubuntu it should be `./myApp`. Where exe even come from? What is exact command you're executing? What is exact name of your executable?

Comment: Thank you very much mate I find executable directory. Thank you .. Now need to find where to be crash or memory leak.. which function or line ? How can I understand.